# Syncronising Calendar and Contacts between Thunberbird and Android using Linux Software

Tags: android, synchronization, calendar

I am looking for software to sync my Calendar and my Contacts between Thunderbird, my Android phones and probably other clients like KDEs Kalendar and Kontacts. I want to have both parts available offline (cached) at least for Thunderbird and for Android.

Google is out of question for obvious security and privacy reasons (can't be trusted).

Which Server software and which way could give me the most success?
Does anyone have partial working solutions with some experience on the stability of the solution? How about the security aspect while syncing across unsecure networks (public hotspots for example)?

Tried so far:
calendarserver (calendar works)
radicale (calendar and adressbook work, but not for android, also lost my adressbook thanks to the sogo extension)

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [Radicale](http://radicale.org/) successfully with Thunderbird for over a year now. It supports SSL and HTTP authentication, which, when used together, should make it safe to sync over and unsecure network.

You mention problems synchronising with Android. In theory any app which supports CalDAV and CardDAV should allow you to sync with Radicale. This page lists several : http://wiki.davical.org/w/CalDAV_Clients/Android

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is super old, but I maintain an instance of Nextcloud on a shared hosting environment, and use `vdirsycner` to sync with Ubuntu and `DAVx5` to sync on Android. I view and edit calendars on Ubuntu with `khal` (`khard` for contacts).